# Check in list and Filter collection using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am removing the users from a user collection using linq as below. Is there a better of doing it? Can I merge the first and second query?

```
List<int> userIDs = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["users"].Split(',').Select(userId =>            Convert.ToInt32(userid)).ToList();

foreach (int userId in userIDs)
{
   userInfoList.RemoveAll(user => (user.UserId.Equals(userId)));
}
```

`UserInfoList` is a collection of users.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will the `userInfoList` be already populated with items and you want to filter it or is this just one step that you take in initializing it?  You'd be able to create the list all at once with a single query.

Comment: userInfoList will be populated. I used Petar Ivanov solution as I will need the original list for some other cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be more efficient:

```
HashSet<int> userIDs = new HashSet<int>(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["users"].Split(',').Select(userId => Convert.ToInt32(userId)));

userInfoList.RemoveAll(user => userIDs.Contains(user.UserId));
```

If you have n elements in userIDs and m elements in userInfoList, then your solution is O(n * m). Using HashSet, the complexity becomes O(n + m) - much better. (Assuming the hash table operations are constant time).

Comment: Actually, you can use `contains` exactly because `user.UserId` is of type `int` (since `userIds` is of type `HashSet<int>`)